# Not Authorized to create a database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Whenever I try to create a db in mongo I get this error:

> not authorized on guilds to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: { name: "guilds" }, cursor: {}, nameOnly: true, lsid: { id: UUID("06da035b-e20b-4cff-b533-e141349b63f3") }, $db: "guilds" }

I have an admin user and logged into compass with it. I gave the user **userAdminAnyDatabase** and I am very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userAdminAnyDatabase does not permit listing collections.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if theres a role that basically gives you all privileges?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#root